# when run the semanage, error happens

Tags: python, selinux

In the centos 6.3, I install the semanage tool
$yum -y install policycoreutils-python
  "Package policycoreutils-python-2.0.83-19.39.el6.x86_64" is installed.
but when I run the below command , error happens

```
$ semanage

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/semanage", line 25, in <module>
    import seobject
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/seobject.py", line 38, in <module>
    import setools
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/setools/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import _sesearch
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libapol.so.4: invalid ELF header
```

python info:

$whereis python

```
  python: /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/python2.6 /usr/lib64/python2.6  /usr/include/python2.6 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
```

$which python

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Comment: do you have multiple versions of Python installed?  "invalid ELF" means the system was expecting something, and got something else. Like the library was compiled for 32 bit but the system is 64 bit.  Uninstall the module, verify it's uninstalled, then do `sudo pip install setools`

Comment: tks! I think I have two versions. the one is the system original python, and another is python2.6 that I installed. But when I run "yum uninstall python", worning error will be appeared, and then failed uninstall. How can I do to uninstall old one?